# Finding lines manually in an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-vision, scikit-image

I have an image (saved as a variable called canny_image) and it looks like this after preprocessing. [image]

I am basically trying to find the distance between the first two vertical lines. I tried using the hough_line function from skimage, but it's unable to find the first line, so I thought it might be easier to solve this manually.

I am basically trying to solve this by going through each row in the image until I get to the first pixel with a value of 255, (the lines have a value of 255, while everything else is zero), and then I store the location of that pixel in an array. And I take the mode of the values in the array as the x location of the first line. I'll do the same for the 2nd line by using the first x-value as a starting point.

```
def find_lines(canny_image):
    threshold = 255
    for y in range(canny_image.shape[0]):
        for x in range(canny_image.shape[1]):
            if canny_image[x, y] == threshold:
                return x
```

This is the code I wrote to get the x-location of the first line, however, I'm not getting the desired output. Any help on how to solve this will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try running `np.mean(img, axis=0)` and you should see peaks where the two lines are,

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try something like this

```
# Returns an array of lines x positions in an image
def find_line_x_positions(image, lines_to_detect: int, buffer_zone: int):
    threshold = 255
    (height, width) = image.shape
    x_position_sums = np.zeros((lines_to_detect, 2), np.double)  # For each line, store x_pos sum[i,0] and point count[i,1]
    for y in range(height):
        buffer = 0
        line_index = 0
        for x in range(width):
            if buffer > 0:
                buffer -= 1
            if (image[y, x] >= threshold) and (buffer == 0):
                buffer = buffer_zone
                x_position_sums[line_index, 0] += x
                x_position_sums[line_index, 1] += 1
                line_index += 1
                if ((line_index) == lines_to_detect):
                    break

    # Divide the x position sums by the point counts to get the average x position for each line
    results = x_position_sums[np.all(x_position_sums,axis=1)]
    results = np.divide(results[:,0],results[:,1])
    return results
```

You can also try [OpenCV's HoughLines() function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) which is simpler to implement than scikit lib. When I tested OpenCV implementation out, it seems to have a hard time finding vertical lines(within 10 degrees from vertical) but you can solve this by rotating your image X degrees and look for lines within that range of rotation.